# Remove mouseenter from an element then restore it (for a jQuery dropdown nav)

Tags: javascript, navigation, jquery-animate, jquery

I'm trying to create a drop down menu using jQuery.

I've got it working but the problem is you can still hover over the subnav that's sliding out while the new one is sliding in. This results in the menu flashing between the two because the `mouseenter` encompasses all of the child elements.

I need some way to remove the `mouseenter` from the subnav `ul` while it's animating then restore it once it's done. It works fine if I change the `.slideUp(300, 'swing')` to `.css('display', 'none')` but then it disappears really abruptly.

UPDATE: I set up a link so you can see the effect. http://samlester.net/nav/

My HTML is in the following format:

```
<nav id="main-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="home" class="current">Home</a></li>
      <li>
           <a href="#">Page 1</a>
         <ul id="page1-subnav">
                <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and here's the JavaScript I've got so far...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var nav = $("#main-nav");

nav.find("li").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find("ul").length > 0) {

        //show submenus on hover
        $(this).mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideDown(300, 'swing');
        });

        //hide submenus on exit
        $(this).mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideUp(300, 'swing');
        });
    }
});

});
```

Thanks, Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - same concept as before with all the logic plugged in.

HTML:

```
<nav id="main-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="home" class="current">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Page 1</a>
            <ul id="page1-subnav">
                <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Page 3</a>
            <ul id="page3-subnav">
                <li><a href="#">Page 3-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3-2</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Page 4</a>
            <ul id="page4-subnav">
                <li><a href="#">Page 4-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 4-2</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#main-nav ul li ul {display:none;}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var nav = $("#main-nav");

    nav.find("li").each(function() 
    {
        if ($(this).find("ul").length > 0) 
        {
            //show submenus on hover
            $(this).mouseenter(function(event) 
            {
                event.stopPropagation();

                if($(this).children('ul').data('interactive') !== false)
                {
                    $(this).children('ul').data('interactive',false);
                    $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideDown(300, 'swing', function(){$(this).data('interactive',true)});
                }
            });

            //hide submenus on exit
            $(this).mouseleave(function(event)
            {
                event.stopPropagation();

                // No if statement here - force close on mouseleave
                $(this).children('ul').data('interactive',false);
                $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideUp(300, 'swing', function(){$(this).data('interactive',true)});

            });
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JE8uH/1/

Comment: Thanks for sticking with this! I think we're closer but when I put the rest of the CSS in the nav still flickers if you move the mouse around the bottom corners of the first level items - http://jsfiddle.net/4XwCg/12/

Comment: The flickering will go away if you add the same if statement to the mouseleave, but it will be touchy if you move your mouse too quickly making it open but not close cuz the mouseleave event happened during the animation. You'll need to add some mouse listener to the body or make a setInterval which always checks if the mouse is over the nav, and if not, closes any stray menus.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic case of event propagation.

Try this:

```
//show submenus on hover
$(this).mouseenter(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideDown(300, 'swing');
});

//hide submenus on exit
$(this).mouseleave(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideUp(300, 'swing');
});
```

To make this cross-browser friendly (IE HACK) you'll want to use this method:

```
try
{
    // Normal browsers use this method from stopping an event from leaving a child dom node up the parent tree
    event.stopPropagation();
}
catch(err)
{
    // IE does it this way
    window.event.cancelBubble=true;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. That didn't work though. I set up a demo so you can see the effect: http://samlester.net/nav

Comment: Ah I see the issue. Yea try setting $(this).data('interactive',FALSE) when you start your slide animation, and then set $(this).data('interactive',TRUE) on the slide animation callback. Then wrap your animation in an if($(this).data('interactive') !== false){ /* do slideUp or slideDown */}

Comment: Just tried it, no effect but I'm not 100% sure I've implemented the fix you suggested properly. Mine's like this at the moment, is that right?

if($(this).data('interactive') !== false) {   

$(this).mouseenter(function(event) {
         $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideDown(300, 'swing');
      $(this).data('interactive',FALSE)

});

     $(this).mouseleave(function(event) {
         $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideUp(300, 'swing');
      $(this).data('interactive',TRUE)

});
     
}

Comment: Woah that's messy without line breaks. Properly formatted code is at the bottom of the demo.

Comment: Nope put that interactive if statement inside the mouseenter(function(event){ and just wrap the animation itself.

Comment: and dont forget to set it to true inside the callback - slideUp(300,'swing',function(){$(this).data('interactive',true);});

Comment: also use lowercase true and false for javascript.

Comment: Ok, I've done that. The subnav isn't disappearing on mouseleave though - not sure what I've missed.